# Is it possible to have two separate css files in the manifest, affecting two separate domains?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

You can have the following:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": [ "style1.css" ],
      "matches": ["http://domain1.com"],    
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

but is it possible to do it for two or more domains? 
Such as the following:
(which I know wouldn't work but for the sake of example)

```
  "content_scripts1": [
    {
      "css": [ "style1.css" ],
      "matches": ["http://domain1.com"],    
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "content_scripts2": [
    {
      "css": [ "style2.css" ],
      "matches": ["http://domain2.com"],    
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

So is this possible to do? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can inject as many different ones as you want. The syntax would be like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "css": ["style1.css"],
  "matches": ["http://domain1.com"]
},
{
  "css": ["style2.css"],
  "matches": ["http://domain2.com"]
}]
```

Comment: @user2352308 Yes, it is allowed. That is why I answered with it. Also, take note of how it is 'content_scripts' with an s and is an array, meaning there is room for more than one.

Comment: Yeah it did not allow that. "invalid port" it says. `Could not load extension. Invalid value for 'content_scripts[1].matches[0]': Invalid port.`

Comment: @user2352308 That is likely a problem with what you put, not the way you put it. What line is throwing that error and what is on that line?

Comment: It does not throw it on any line. I gave you the error. **EDIT:** nevermind I fixed the issue. I had http:http://domain2.com/ Anyway Looks like the solution! Let me test it.